# ImGuiNET - Show OpenCV Video Stream

Tags: c#, opencv, user-interface, graphics, imgui

I want to display a series of processed OpenCV/EmguCV `UMat` in an ImGui Window.
I'm re-using most of this Code as "Backend" for my Application:

https://github.com/ImGuiNET/ImGui.NET/tree/master/src/ImGui.NET.SampleProgram

I already found out that I need to convert the `UMat` to `TextureData` and use an `ImTextureID` to display that Data.

But how would I convert it? I couldn't find any useable/reliable Documentation on this topic.

I tried to hack something together using [This Part of `imgui_demo.h`](https://github.com/ocornut/imgui/blob/956a1a17fb8f8d72726cad92f203cdd57470eae7/imgui_demo.cpp#L1044-L1056), but I could not get it to work.

I'm not exactly an "expert" in ImGui/Veldrid (the Backend i'm using)

Can someone help or at least provide me with a "direction" to go on?